# Set Title in MainWindow.xaml using Resource string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got a C# WPF solution that contains a single project named WpfApp2.

I'm trying to set the Main Window title from the `Properties/Resources.resx` file.

I've added a string to the resources file and set the Access Modifier to `Public`.

I've also added a namespace to `MainWindow.xaml`

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:WpfApp2.Properties"
```

When setting the Window title, I'm using:

```
 Title="{p:Resources.PRODUCT_NAME}"
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Nested types are not supported: Resources.PRODUCT_NAME
```

Comment: `Title="{x:Static p:Resources.PRODUCT_NAME}"`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Title="{x:Static p:Resources.PRODUCT_NAME}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectNameSpace.SubNameSpace.Resources"
```

...so it should be WpfApp2.Properties.Resources...

```
<Window Title ="{x:Static local:PRODUCT_NAME}">
</Window>
```